# Why will this Rails Gem will not freeze?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have added the following to my environment.rb:

```
config.gem "json", :version => '>=1.2.3'
```

When I run

```
rake rails:freeze:gems
```

the json gem does not install. I get

```
Freezing to the gems for Rails 2.3.8
rm -rf vendor/rails
mkdir -p vendor/rails
cd vendor/rails
Unpacked gem: '/Users/chad/www/aromapersona.localhost/vendor/rails/activesupport-2.3.8'
mv activesupport-2.3.8 activesupport
Unpacked gem: '/Users/chad/www/aromapersona.localhost/vendor/rails/activerecord-2.3.8'
mv activerecord-2.3.8 activerecord
Unpacked gem: '/Users/chad/www/aromapersona.localhost/vendor/rails/actionpack-2.3.8'
mv actionpack-2.3.8 actionpack
Unpacked gem: '/Users/chad/www/aromapersona.localhost/vendor/rails/actionmailer-2.3.8'
mv actionmailer-2.3.8 actionmailer
Unpacked gem: '/Users/chad/www/aromapersona.localhost/vendor/rails/activeresource-2.3.8'
mv activeresource-2.3.8 activeresource
Unpacked gem: '/Users/chad/www/aromapersona.localhost/vendor/rails/rails-2.3.8'
cd -
```

I have also tried

```
rake gems:unpack:dependencies
```

and

```
rake gems:unpack
```

but I get no output, and the gem still is not installed.

Am I running the wrong command? Am I misunderstanding something?

Note: I already have some gems installed at vendor/gems. I don't remember how I did this.

Comment: I haven't played with freezing gems before, so I can't really answer your question, but have you looked into using Bundler (https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler) to manage your dependencies? It is the new standard for Rails (or any Ruby-based) applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110535/unpacking-freezing-gems-into-a-non-rails-ruby-app/1110756#1110756).

```
cd vendor/gems
gem unpack active_support
```